# Translating GPS coordinates to map tile-like structure

Tags: postgresql, gps, gis, postgis

I'm a complete illiterate when it comes to working with geographical data, so bear with me.

For our application we will be tracking a fairly large amount of rapidly changing points on a map. It would be nice to be able to cache the location of these points in some kind of map-tile structure so it would be easy to find all points currently in the same tile or neighbouring tiles, making it easier to quickly determine the nearest neigbours and have special logic for specific tiles, etc.

Although we're working for one specific (but already large) location, it would be nice if a solution would scale to other locations as well. Since we would only cache tiles that concern the system, would just tiling the enitre planet be the best option? The dimensions of a tile would then be measured in arc seconds/minutes, or is that a bad idea?

We already work with Postgres and this seems like something that could be done with PostGIS (is this what rasters are?), but jumping in to the documentation/tutorials without knowing what exactly I'm looking for is proving difficult. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

PostGIS is all that you need. It can store your points in any coordinate reference system, but you'll probably be using longitude/latitude. Are your points coming from a GPS device?

PostGIS uses GIST indexing, making the search for points close to a given point quite efficient. One option you might want to look at, seeing that you are interested in tiling, is to "geohash" your points. Basically, this turns an (X,Y) coordinate pair into a single "string" with a length depending on the level of partitioning. Nearby points will have the same geohash value (= 1 tile) and are then easily identified with standard database search tools. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22603215/3304426) and related question for some more considerations and an example in PostgreSQL.

You do not want to look at rasters. These are gridded data, think aerial photography or satellite images, weather maps, etc.

But if you want a more specific answer you should give some more details:

- How many points? How are they collected?
- Do you have large clusters?
- Local? Regional? Global?
- What other data does this relate to?
- Pseudo table structure? Data layout?
- etc

More info = better answer

Cheers, hope you get your face back

Comment: A geohash key partition is all the same. This is not good answer. A geohash has different precisions and then the lenght of the key is different.

Comment: @Phpdevpad How can you say that the answer is bad? Do you know exactly what the OP wants maybe? I suggested him to have a look at it. If you know so much better, perhaps you should write an answer yourself.

Comment: The answer you give in the link is also not a good answer. IMO a bounding box or a r-tree or a quadtree gives better or similar results. Also there are many possibilities to traverse a n-dim space, geohash is very easy to implement.